# Receiving onActivityResult in Android NDK for AccountPicker

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate my NDK application with Google Drive. I am following the [Sample Application](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) and adapting it to being used from my native code. I have gotten it to launch the account picker successfully, but am now stuck at how to get the result from the account picker. I launch the account picker using JNI calls from my code

In the code sample, the `onActivityResult` method is called on the activity when other intents return.

```java
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
        String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        if (accountName != null) {
          credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
          service = getDriveService(credential);
          startCameraIntent();
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to do a similar thing using the NDK? I want to create a function in C and set it as the callback for `onActivityResult`.

Comment: What is the problem with the posted code?

Comment: @krsteeve there is no problem with the posted code. My problem is that I am using the ndk and my application uses NativeActivity, so I have no idea of how to do the same from the nativeactivity side. How to create a function and set it as the callback for onActivityResult like here. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Did you find answer?  I am facing the same issue @codemonkey

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is a less than ideal one. You have to create a Java subclass of NativeActivity, and implement onActivityResult result there. In your AndroidManifest.xml you'll reference your new subclass `activity android:name=""` instead of NativeActivity.