# How to implement onactivityresult in native activity

Tags: android-ndk

I'm working on a project that require full-NDK (which connects to other project written in Java) and I have problems about activity intent in NDK. 
Questions about how to pass an intent are asked and answered widely here, but rarely there's any answer about get the result back from the intent.
like this:
[Receiving onActivityResult in Android NDK for AccountPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073962/receiving-onactivityresult-in-android-ndk-for-accountpicker)

Now I can send a intent to start a java activity from native activity using startactivityforresult(),but 
I can't override onactivityforresult because there is no such thing as "override" in JNI, without overriding the method,I can't get any result.

The systematic callback is useless for native activity only provides callback about cycles of the acitivity and window adjustment, leaving no callback for receive activity result from previous one.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time of thinking, with the help of colleagues, there's something for sure.

Google haven't provide any method to do so. That is, startActivityforResult() is useless in such kind of situation.

If the parameter passing is required, there's a workaround that using freespace created by native side.

Native Activity creates space for parameters (use malloc or so), and method that can access to it for java to use. (Or just write socket, Right?)